# Intellisense doesn't work for custom xml files in Xamarin

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I use Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.
In Layout axml files intellisense works normal as shown in the picture.

[image: Layout axml file]

But, in the main_menu.xml file intellisense doesn't work.

[image: Custom xml file]

Is there any solution or this feature is not intended?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any trouble getting XML IntelliSense for the AXML files in Visual Studio, please follow the steps below.

**Step1:**
                Open an (any) .Axml file

**Step2:**
                From the menu bar, select XML -> Schemas…

**Step3:**
               In the XML Schemas dialog, click on Add

**Step4:**
               Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android

**Step5:**
              Select android-layout-xml.xsd and click on Open.

**Step6:**
             Click on OK.

I hope above steps useful for you

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, intellisense works in AXML files for layout. My problem is with xml files. For example, I have created xml file for action bar. In this xml file intellisense doesn't work.